# After filling a list dynamically (at runtime) even if I add a delegate listener I have to click two times to trigger click-event

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I fill a list (e.g. unordered list) dinamically (at runtime: e.g. Ajax), even if I add a delegate listener, the first click never works. Only after second click the event is triggered. Does anyone know why? What's wrong?

**Without delegation**

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="my-textbox"/>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var sayHello = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Hi");
    };

    var fillList = function (e) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var $ul = $('#list').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            var $a = $('<a href="#">').text("List item " + i).on("click", sayHello);
            var $li = $('<li>').append($a);
            $ul.append($li);
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my-textbox").on("keyup, change", fillList)
            .bind("input propertychange", fillList);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

---

**With delegation** (scope to difference only)

```
    var fillList = function (e) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var $ul = $('#list').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            var $a = $('<a href="#">').text("List item " + i); // here edited
            var $li = $('<li>').append($a);
            $ul.append($li);
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#list").on("click", 'a', sayHello); // and here edited
        $("#my-textbox").on("keyup, change", fillList)
            .bind("input propertychange", fillList);
    });
```

---

Again: first click does not work in both cases. After second click, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved. I thoud you use `bind("input propertychange")` to be sure if you paste text from clipboard, a `change` (on textbox) is triggered. So, if you use `bind("input propertychange")`, using `on("keyup, change")` is redundant.

```
    $("#my-textbox").bind("input propertychange", fillList); // so this is enough; this works
```